# laravel syntax error, unexpected 'assets' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to load laravel project but getting error below

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected 'assets' (T_STRING)
```

[image]

Its under views/myview.blade.php, I don't understand why its throwing error on assets, here is my view code

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="1000" height="563"
          poster="{{ asset('assets/public/video/video.png')}}"
          data-setup="{}">
```

When I change the path to somepath/public/video/video.png then error is unexpected 'somepath'. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel, but is assets a function you made? There may be a syntax error in there

Comment: that's laravel function in library Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php. that is fine

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a closing single-quote on this line:

```
videojs.options.flash.swf = "<?php echo asset('assets/js/plugins/video-js/video-js.swf); ?>";
```

So by the time you get to line 29, you're actually closing the string you started there, and the next thing is `assets`.